# "Until you apologised" vs. "until you have apologised" vs. "until you apologise"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses, dependent-clause

What is the most correct way of saying to someone that I won't speak to him before he has apologised.

> 1. I won't speak to you until you have apologised for what you have done.
> 2. I won't speak to you until you apologised for what you have done.
> 3. I won't speak to you until you apologise for what you have done.
> 4. I won't speak to you until you have apologised for what you did.
> 5. I won't speak to you until you apologised for what you did.
> 6. I won't speak to you until you apologise for what you did.

Answer (score 3):

1, 3, 4, and 6 are all reasonable choices, but of these, 6 is the most common and generally accepted choice. It is the most direct, succinct, and effective way of saying it.

2 and 5 are not acceptable. "Apologised" is not the correct tense to coordinate with "until," because "until" must refer to something that will occur in the future; "apologised" cannot be in the future (unless it is modified in some way, such as adding "have").

Comment: Do you think there is a difference between American English and British English for this (for this, on this or in this? I'm confused)?

Comment: "On this" would be correct ("on this matter"). I seriously doubt that British English could differ from what I have said here, because it seems to me a fairly basic grammatical point, not much subject to interpretation or debate. (Also note that I retained your British spelling of "apologise" even though I'm American, so if you thought I would answer your comment from the British point of view, that's probably why.)

Comment: On the other hand, British English does have some locutions that seem preposterous to us Yanks, just as we say some things that sound equally preposterous to the British, so I could be quite wrong; maybe there IS some difference between the British and American views of this question.

Comment: The British view is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:

1. OK
2. not OK
3. OK
4. OK
5. not OK
6. OK

Either *have apologised* or *apologise* can be used.

"What you did" and "what you have done" are both fine.